# How can I delete Windows restore points in c#?

Tags: c#, windows, wmi

Im looking for a way to delete Windows restore points using C# perhaps by invoking WMI.

Any code snippet would be very helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Touching on what Morten said you can use that API.  WMI doesn't provide a method to delete a Restore Point as far as I can tell.  The SRRemoveRestorePoint can remove a restore point, provided you have the sequence number.  You can get that through WMI.  Here is my code to Remove a restore point.

```
[DllImport("Srclient.dll")]
public static extern int SRRemoveRestorePoint(int index);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int SeqNum = 335;
    int intReturn = SRRemoveRestorePoint(SeqNum);
}
```

I just threw in 335 since that was the farthest one back as I could find on my system.  Its likely that the count starts at 1 and keeps incrementing.  so it isn't as simple as just having an index like you would in an array.

As for getting the sequence numbers, I converted the code from [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=295299) to C# which will give you that info.  Be sure to add System.Management as a reference. Otherwise this code won't work right.

```
    private void EnumRestorePoints()
    {
        System.Management.ManagementClass objClass = new System.Management.ManagementClass("\\\\.\\root\\default", "systemrestore", new System.Management.ObjectGetOptions());
        System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection objCol = objClass.GetInstances();

        StringBuilder Results = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject objItem in objCol)
        {
            Results.AppendLine((string)objItem["description"] + Convert.ToChar(9) + ((uint)objItem["sequencenumber"]).ToString());
        }

        MessageBox.Show(Results.ToString());
    }
```

I tested this on my box (Vista by the way) and it worked without issue.  Also have to be running as Admin, but I think you figured that.

Answer (score 0):

While I know nothing about WMI, [this](http://www.csharphelp.com/archives2/archive334.html) resource might get you started. It does not directly touch your issue, but perhaps it can be useful somehow. Anyhow, it seems that the relevant Win32/COM function is [SRRemoveRestorePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378934.aspx). I hope this was of any use.

Alternatively, you can work with [VBScript](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=295299), if you're so inclined.